# Best way to fetch a global variable for a thrift service from a client

Tags: java, php, thrift

I have a client server architecture set up through thrift. The service has been written in java, while the client is in php. Now, as the clients might be many, I want to introduce the concept of something like unique client Id.

The current structure is such that all the clients have the same client code at their end. Hence, the only way for me to determine the client Id is to do it when a request is made.

As the service has a lot of exposed functions(>50), I would not like to add the client Id as a parameter in all the functions (as that would mean a changes for ALL the clients).

Is there a clean way to do this - when the client makes the service object for the first time, it sends its Id, which becomes a global object for the service thread. For all subsequent calls to the exposed functions, the client id thus becomes a global object for the service thread. Please guide.

Comment: So, what did you try so far and why is it not working?

Comment: I tried writing a wrapper for the client, which takes the client Id as an argument in the constructor for the service object. This means that if I make the clientId a parameter in EVERY function, I only have to ask for the clientId once in the constructor, and the client would not have to send it in every function call. This still means the introduction of the new parameter in every function though, something which I want to avoid. I am basically stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use client IP address for the reference.

["how can i get the client's from the thrift server"](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201110.mbox/%3C9162DA16-0B63-47DA-BB30-EFFDCFDE017F@gmail.com%3E)

It looks like subclassing TServerSocket/TNonBlockingServerSocket (and your chosen server class) will allow you to access the IP address (or hostname) pretty easily right from the Sockets they manage...

Answer (score 0):

Given that you simply want the clientid to be available globally - you should [simply global it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). If that doesn't fit within the oop pattern, you could cover it up with a [registry pattern](http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/basic/practical-php-patterns-0), although it's just sugarcoating really.